# Android studio styles and themes error

Tags: java, android

I made a simple flashlight app and I released a few updates. I didn't do anything and the IDE somehow got buggy. I did a lot of googling and i still couldn't fix it. There were over 250 errors.
Here's the project:
https://github.com/Camper1233/Flashlight_original/

Comment: Did you try cleaning it?

Comment: Yes, i did try, but it did nothing.

Comment: Try changing the API level. May be it will help.

Comment: Already tried. I also tried changing the build number and even themes.

Comment: invalidate cache and restart..?

Comment: I tried that too, it didn't work.